# SQLite3 error - iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

How can I figure out the error that SQLite3 is giving me when I make an SQL call:

```
int success = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);

if(success != SQLITE_OK) {
  NSLog(@"create stmt failed %@",stmt);
}
```

All as I know is if it failed, but is there a way to get the actual error, or reason why it failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, if `success != SQLITE_OK`, then it must be one of these error codes:

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: The `success` variable contains the error code. `SQLITE_OK` is just one of the many error codes. The `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` function returns the error code.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `sqlite3_errmsg` function. You need to pass in the db handle. The following code will log the error

```
NSLog(@"Error %s while preparing statement", sqlite3_errmsg(_dbHandle));
```

Comment: to clarify "dbHandle" is "database" from question