# Not able to UPDATE the SQlite3 table

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I have done lot of googling on updating the created sqlite table still i did not able to update my table in my sample app .Can any one please tell me what is wrong with my  below code .IT works fine till **sqlite3_prepare_v2**.Once it reach **if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)** condition it is not going into this if() condition can any one tell what is happening here?

```
const char *dbpath = [[self DBPath] UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Table1 SET AppEndTime = %@ WHERE AppID= %d",AppEndTime,appID];
    const char *sql=[querySql UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, sessionID);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [sessionEndTime UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    }
}
char* errmsg;
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement)){
    NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
else{
   sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: Don't you have any log message? Maybe you have to quote the value of AppEndTime in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace you code as given below.I hope it will solve your problem.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &Statement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_text(Statement1, 1, [status UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(Statement1, 2, [messageID UTF8String], -1, NULL);

        int success = sqlite3_step(Statement1);
        if(success != SQLITE_ERROR)
        {
        //  NSLog(@"Success");
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(Statement1);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . but you answer couldnt reslove my problem can you plz edit my code so that i can understand better

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which update created table. Have a look hope it'll help you.

```
-(BOOL)updateMyTable{
BOOL isGood = YES;
@try {

    NSString *fName = [user_dic valueForKey:@"fName"];

    NSString *lName = [user_dic valueForKey:@"lName"];

    NSString *email_id = [user_dic valueForKey:@"email_id"];

    NSString *employee_id = [user_dic valueForKey:@"employee_id"];

    fName= [fName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
    lName= [lName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
    email_id= [email_id stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
    employee_id= [employee_id stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"''"];
    // NSString *autoId = [user_dic valueForKey:@"autoId"];

    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE tbl_profile SET fName = '%@', lName  = '%@', email_id  = '%@' ,employee_id = '%@' WHERE autoId = '%@'",fName,lName,email_id,employee_id,autoId];

    [database executeUpdate:sql,nil];
    if (MyDelegate.isLogging) {
        NSLog(@"edit user QUERY---- >>>>%@",sql);
        NSLog(@"edit user RESULT CODE ---- >>>>%d:", [database lastErrorCode]);
        NSLog(@"edit user RESULT ERROR MESSAGE ---- >>>>%@",[database lastErrorMessage]);
    }

}@catch (NSException *exception) {
    isGood = NO;
}
@finally {

}

return isGood;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your Sqlite file is in the documents directory,Not in project folder.
Update and insert will work if and only if the file is in the document directory

[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205284/1704346)